# Using variables to write down links on the page

Tags: javascript

my question is if its possible to use javascript to write out the website urls as links on the page that are stored on a variable? I have the following code, perhaps I am doing it wrong.
Any help would be appreciated

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  var website = ["http://www.stackoverflow.com","http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
  document.write(("<p><a href="+website[0]+"/></p>"));
  document.write(("<p><a href="+website[1]+"/></p>"));

</script
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You have some typos and syntax issues here though. What is the full HTML source and the rendered output?

Comment: The code you posted works fine, it just doesn't have any link text so you aren't seeing the links. Try: `document.write(("<p><a href="+website[0]+">"+website[0]+"</a></p>"));`

Comment: use `for` loop to generate links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var website =
       ["http://www.stackoverflow.com","http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
    document.write(('<p><a href="'+website[0]+'"/>1st link</a></p>'));
    document.write(('<p><a href="'+website[1]+'"/>second link</a></p>'));
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this code and it woks perfectly! :D Like Rob M mentioned, I had no text so it wont show properly!

Comment: Yes, you also missed closing the </a> and in my example I made it a little easier to read by using the ' instead of only " (some code readers prefer it and I've grown accustomed to doing it this way).  If you like the answer, please consider marking it 'correct' - thanks! (I'm trying to get my points up!)